# Angular dnd-allowed-types doesn't allow drag and drop

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop

I have this HTML. In this state it will not allow me to drag elements into it.

```
<ul
    dnd-list="tabs"
    dnd-allowed-types="['tab']"
    >
    <li
        ng-repeat="tab in tabs"
        dnd-draggable="tabTemplate"
        dnd-moved="tabs.splice($index, 1)"
        dnd-type="tab.type">
            {{tab.label}} ({{tab.type}})
    </li>
</ul>
```

If I remove `dnd-allowed-types="['tab']"` it will allow me to drag elements.

I've tried changing the `dnd-type` to be 'tab' and it still doesn't work.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?